# ElasticSearch: "Object field starting or ending with a [.] makes object resolution ambiguous: []"

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm getting the error "object field starting or ending with a [.] makes object resolution ambiguous: []". But there isn't a single dot [.] in my object. Using `elasticClient.update()` I'm passing:

```
{
    "index": "applicants",
    "type": "applicant",
    "id": "A01gfGEBKfWmu0nhvuR7",
    "body": {
        "doc": {
            "phsEmploymentHistory": {
                "numSickDaysNotIll": "4",
                "employers": [{
                    "employmentType": {},
                    "": {},
                    "name": null,
                    "supervisor": null,
                    "contactNumber": null,
                    "extension": null,
                    "email": null,
                    "coworker1": null,
                    "coworker2": null,
                    "duties": null,
                    "jobTitle": null,
                    "reasonLeaving": null,
                    "fullTime": null,
                    "partTime": null,
                    "temp": null,
                    "selfEmployed": null,
                    "volunteer": null,
                    "duration": {
                        "startDate": null,
                        "endDate": null
                    },
                    "address": {
                        "street": null,
                        "city": null,
                        "state": null,
                        "zip": null
                    }
                }],
                "agencies": [{
                    "": {},
                    "agencyName": null,
                    "backgroundInvestigator": null,
                    "contactNumber": null,
                    "extension": null,
                    "position": null,
                    "email": null,
                    "stepsCompleted": null,
                    "dateApplied": null,
                    "status": null,
                    "address": {
                        "street": null,
                        "city": null,
                        "state": null,
                        "zip": null
                    }
                }],
                "disciplined": {
                    "response": false,
                    "explanation": ""
                },
                "warnedDrugs": {
                    "response": false,
                    "explanation": ""
                },
                "valid": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been over this several times. I don't think the error message is adequate. The "object resolution ambiguous: []" seems to hint that I have an empty array, but I don't.

Comment: Both employers and agencies have this line "": {}. I am curious about this. Also, can you show the mapping details as well?

Comment: Whoa, good catch. I haven't made a mapping for this yet. I will try to figure out what the empty property name is coming from. This is probably the issue.

Comment: Let me know if it works, I can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Values of the json could be empty. But if the keys are empty then ES throws error while indexing.
Remove `"":{}` from the json and index again.

Reference:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/object-field-starting-or-ending-with-a-makes-object-resolution-ambiguous/123351